# Analytic curve fit: one Gauss curve fitting a bimodal model

Tags: r, math, optimization, scipy, curve-fitting

**Problem:**

I have a completely **noise-free** model ytot which is the sum of two perfect Gaussian curves:

```
> y0 = A0 * exp( (x-mu0)^2/(2*std0^2) ) 
> y1 = A1 * exp( (x-mu1)^2/(2*std1^2) ) 
> y = y0 + y1
```

I now need to fit them via least sqaures curve fit as a **SINGLE** Gauss curve.

**Question:**

As I know the true ytot (completely noise-free): is there any analytical solution that represents what a least sqaures optimizer does in this case? E.g. analytically solving a Jacobian or gradient for this case?

**More info:**

The least sqaures curve fit can be done e.g. in Python using scipy.optimize's curve_fit or minimize functions. However, I have to perform this fit millions of times for different parameters, making this a bottleneck to my code.

Note: I can **NOT** use the statistical point of view here (e.g. mu=p*mu0+(1-p)*mu1 and so on). Both approaches lead to very similar solutions if mu0~mu1 and std0~std1, but differ systematically with increasing bimodularity.

Comment: The question of an analytical solution to the least-squares problem might be more appropriate over at https://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution after two days of thinking and linear algebra. I hope this will be useful to others in the future.

Instead of fitting a Gaussian to y, one can fit a parabola to log(y). A parabolic least squares problem can be easily solved via linear algebra, see e.g. in this [google doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1vXgizn0Zz5VM_mTEfrRqwydfCyn0OY5DNlkieFLRU68/edit) and this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YwZYSTQs-Hk).

This is prone to outliers on the wings, so one has to use a [weighted least square model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares#Weighted_least_squares). I used weights = y^2.

Of course, right after figuring it out, I found this very clear [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/252062037_A_Simple_Algorithm_for_Fitting_a_Gaussian_Function_DSP_Tips_and_Tricks) that outlines exactly the same approach. Please see the paper for the detailed solution.